# Adding all values of map using std::accumulate

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, accumulate

I am simply trying to add values of a map defined in the program below:

```
std::map<int, int> floor_plan;

const size_t distance = std::accumulate(std::begin(floor_plan), std::end(floor_plan), 0);

std::cout << "Total: " << distance;
```

I get the following error:

> Error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::plus::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`std::begin(floor_plan)` gives you an iterator pointing at `std::map<int, int>::value_type` which is `std::pair<const int, int>`. Since there is no `operator+` defined for this pair type and an integer, your code fails to compile.

#### Option #1

If you want to sum up all the mapped values from `floor_plan`, you'd need to provide your own binary operator that is able to extract the second element of a dereferenced iterator passed in:

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(floor_plan)
              , std::end(floor_plan)
              , 0
              , [] (int value, const std::map<int, int>::value_type& p)
                   { return value + p.second; }
               );
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/552b949866773d29)

#### Option #2

Alternatively, you could exploit the *Boost.Iterator* library to extract the second element of a pair on the fly with [`boost::make_transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <functional>

auto second = std::mem_fn(&std::map<int, int>::value_type::second);
std::accumulate(boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(floor_plan), second)
              , boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(floor_plan), second)
              , 0);
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7160ed84ecc3b2)

#### Option #3

Another approach is to use the *Boost.Range* library along with its own implementation of the `accumulate` algorithm:

```
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>

boost::accumulate(floor_plan | boost::adaptors::map_values, 0);
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/487a70584d5c0697)

Comment: is there a way not to start from std:begin but from say, 3rd element. Can I do something like std::being(floor_plan) + 3 ? but this gives an error.

Comment: @Daqs `std::next(std::begin(floor_plan), 3)` in place of `std::begin`

Comment: Rather than "const std::map<int, int>::value_type& p" you can use "const auto& p"

Comment: what does `int value` refer to?

Comment: @J.L.Louis accumulated value so far

Answer (score 4):

Piotr S. answer is right, but if this is not a one-time task, you better make a simple convenient functor for such tasks:

```
struct AddValues
{
  template<class Value, class Pair> 
  Value operator()(Value value, const Pair& pair) const
  {
    return value + pair.second;
  }
};

const size_t distance = std::accumulate(plan.begin(), plan.end(), 0, AddValues());
```

Thank to templated `operator()` you can use this functor for any `map` in your code. This is much like transparent comparator, but this is transparent "summator".

Answer (score 1):

I will show you not only how does it works.

**`accumulate` Possible implementation as below**(as we may sum from a base value, so there is a `init` value):

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init,
             BinaryOperation op)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = op(std::move(init), *first); // std::move since C++20
    }
    return init;
}
```

So when we wants to get `sum/product` of a `vector`, it may like this:

```
vector<int> vec(5);
std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);

cout<<"vec: ";// output vec
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
// vec: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,

cout<<"\n vec sum is: "<<accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0)<<endl;
// vec sum is: 15

cout<<"vec product is: "<<accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>())<<endl;
// vec product is: 120
```

As to `std::map`, you wants to sum the second value of an `map`, so you have to get each `second item` in map. So you should get the `value_type` in `map` and then get the second item. `value_type` in `map` is defined as below:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class map{
    // using re_tree to sort
    typedef Key    key_type;

    // rb_tree value type
    typedef std::pair<key_type, value_type> value_type;
};
```

For example, get the sum of all the `second/first` value:

```
typedef map<string, int> IdPrice;
IdPrice idPrice = {{"001", 100}, {"002", 300}, {"003", 500}};

int sum = accumulate(idPrice.begin(), idPrice.end(), 0, [](int v, const IdPrice::value_type& pair){
    return v + pair.second;
    // if we want to sum the first item, change it to 
    // return v + pair.first;
});
cout<<"price sum is: "<<sum<<endl; // price sum is: 900
```

The para `v` in the above `lambda funtion`, stores the tmp sum, with init value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use lambda expression with `pair<int,int>` as the binary operation.

```
distance = std::accumulate(std::begin(floor_plan), std::end(floor_plan), 0,
                   [](int value, pair<int,int> p) { return value + p.second; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
  // Create a map with some initial key-value pairs
  std::map<std::string, int> m = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};

  // Use std::accumulate to add up all of the values in the map
  int sum = std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0,
    [](int total, const std::pair<std::string, int>& p) {
      return total + p.second;
    });

  // Print the sum of the values in the map
  std::cout << "The sum of the values in the map is " << sum << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be just a re-hash of the first part of the accepted answer.  It doesn't add any new value to the question.